# webdriver - url parameters don't work when I open page using webdriver. They work correctly when I open the browser manually

Tags: java, rest, selenium, webdriver

I have to open the chrome browser using webdriver using the url that has a few parameters. Depending upon the parameters the flow of my website will differ. This works correctly when I access my page manually on a browser. Below are the exemple of the url :-

https://.com/en/account/signinwithticket?ticketId=16795&hash=2ae74c8a8a088a691&checkout=false&redirect=/en/payment

I compared the cookies of the webdriver browser and the browser I open manually. So, all the cookies corresponding to the REST parameters are set correctly when I try manually. But when the browser opens on webdriver these cookies are not set. Can there be a specific chromedriver capability or options to solve this issue.

Just as an FYI - I am using the usual way of opening the browser - WebDriver.get("url");

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155759/how-can-i-refresh-my-selenium-chromedriver-instance-without-losing-the-cookies , but no answer yet! :-(

Comment: Needs clarification. Are you saying: locally <clear cookies>, request url, cookies are created; WebDriver <clear cookies>, request url, **no cookies are created**? I'm very interested in this one, because I can't see how it wouldn't work, or how anyone could test effectively with Chrome if this didn't work.

Comment: ... especially given that it's good practice to run tests completely clean: zapping cookies either at the start or end of the test run.

Comment: Works fine and consistently for me: start clean Chrome (v48, Driver 2.19, Sel 2.48), check no cookies, load JSFiddle page that sets cookie, check cookie is set, zap cookies.

Comment: @AndrewRegan - Thanks for you reply. I tried again by changing the version combination you have provided for browser, driver and selenium. Still same problem.

Comment: That's fine, I'm not telling you to change versions, just wanted to show that this can potentially be accomplished without any special work. Could you confirm my 2nd comment ^^ and consider posting your Java code?